# list of all props and states of any component in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm

Is there any simple way to get all props and states of any component in react native? I would like to see them in a list and the data type of any prop.

(I asked this question because there is the nice IDE [Deco](https://www.decoide.org/) that shows the props of any used component just by dragging and dropping it on the editor or clicking on that component. Since I am using Windows and there is no stable version of deco for windows, I would like to know any other ways to do so. Either by using another IDE or by typing a command or what so ever...)

Comment: Use [React development tools](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/blob/master/README.md), available as browser extension (for Chrome and Firefox) or as a standalone app.

Comment: is that for react native too ?? (sorry i am very naive when it comes to that)

Comment: You can simply use `console.log(this);` inside of the Render method because the scope of this is the entire access of the component, so state and props is readily available.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I cannot comment yet... Yes, you can use react developer tools for react native too. Use:

```
npm install --save-dev react-devtools
```

then in your package.json in scripts add:

```
"devtools": "react-devtools"
```

and then in a terminal

```
npm run devtools
```

Comment: i will try it and will let you know how it goes

Comment: I Tried React development tools as i understood its nice for seeing components AFTER i compiled , to see how page structured which is useful , but I was asking not after debugging and running , rather i need to see list of all props and states of any component while I use them in the code , because there are ton of components out there and some lack documentation . For example , i use some component XYZ , when i write the tag XYZ i want to see all possible props.